# Basic header-navbar-footer-content layout in Tailwind + CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I'm looking to create a basic layout with Tailwind + CSS, with a fixed-height header, fixed-height footer, fixed-width nav bar, and content filling the rest, where the entire containing area expands to fill the available space, like this:

[image]

I've gotten this far in futzing with the [Tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/):

```
<div class="flex min-h-full w-full flex-col bg-slate-400 grow">
  <div class="flex h-32 w-screen bg-red-400">Title</div>
  <div class="flex h-auto w-screen flex-row grow">
    <div class="flex w-32 bg-yellow-300">Nav</div>
    <div class="flex w-full bg-blue-400">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex h-32 w-screen bg-green-400">Footer</div>
</div>
```

but the nav/content height doesn't expand to fill the available vertical space.  If I swap `h-auto` in `<div class="flex h-auto w-screen flex-row grow">` for `h-screen`, then it expands beyond the host div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Word Break`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/word-break) utility.

There's a comprehensive explanation about all the different kinds of word breaks in the link above, but when you apply `flex` to your elements, you lose the word break. Here's a code-pen demostrating it: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/lehollandaisvolant/pen/MvOYxp)

Also, you don't have to use as many `flex` classes as you used; you only need to apply them to the parent element.

I would also suggest creating a minimum width for your nav bar, for example, `min-w-[8rem]`.

Here's a tailwind playground I created with all the things I wrote above: [Link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/RXCRRSKsTn)

Example with the `w-screen min-h-screen`: [Link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/XaYp0MA37j)

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  That second link (specifically `min-h-screen`) is exactly what I needed.  It uses just as many `flex` classes as my code, though - which ones are removable?

Comment: I created the second example with your original code, so I didn't think it was necessary to remove it again. In general, I would remove the `flex` class from any element that isn't a parent element (unless you don't want the elements to be flexible). Think about it as a chart; you apply the `flex` class on the "header," the parent of your cells. Then your cells will act flexibly. I hope I explained it clearly :)
Here's a link for another tailwind play without the over-used `flex` classes; you can compare the two to understand the usage better: [Link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/QaPr5fCHyP)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't **Tailwind**, so it won't be of direct use to you.

But, when adopting frameworks, it's always useful to have a vanilla comparison so we can see how things *would* be coded, if we weren't using the framework.

So, for the sake of having a reference to compare against, here's the same layout:

> fixed-height header, fixed-height footer, fixed-width nav bar, and
> content filling the rest, where the entire containing area expands to
> fill the available space

but using:

- **HTML5 Sectioning Elements**
- **CSS Grid**

---

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid: 80px auto 80px / 120px auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  background-color: rgb(255, 174, 201);
}

footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  background-color: rgb(181, 230, 29);
}

nav {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  background-color: rgb(255, 242, 0);
}

main {
  background-color: rgb(153, 217, 234);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header></header>
  <main></main>
  <nav></nav>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```